# cURL - works in browser, not in cURL

Tags: php, debugging, curl

I have been struggling for almost three days now on this task, and I guess I am missing on some basic cURL skills.

I start with:

In the F12 of IE I see 2 POSTs on the first page:  (I notice the first one is getting a 302 which is supposed to be a redirect, and with cURL I only get 200)

Filling up the captcha:

on the second page (after captcha):

traffic:

This is my code (and I cannot move on with it because it doesn't work for the early stages):

I Built a special form that submits to my own page with `GET` (with the cURL) which in turn is accessing the website:

```
$id=$_GET['id']; // getting the biznumber
$humanCode=$_GET['nobot'];

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.*******.******.***");


// setting some https to be able to access the website from my local computer.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "c:/xampp/htdocs/CAcerts/curl-ca-bundle.crt");

// I know the values for the ASPX vars like __EVENTTARGET, __EVENTARGUMENT, __VIEWSTATE are arbitrary now. I need to take care of that but I don't yet know how.

$postarr= array (
                "__EVENTTARGET"=>"",
                "__VIEWSTATE=" =>"%2FwEPDwULLTEzMzI2OTg4NDYPZBYCZg9kFgQCBA8PZBYCHgdvbmNsaWNrBQxnb1RvTWl2emFrKClkAgYPD2QWAh8ABQxnb1RvTWl2emFrKClkZM6iZZ0Qaf2CpfXoJJdZ0IqaWsDO",
                "__EVENTARGUMENT=" =>"",
                "__EVENTVALIDATION" =>"%2FwEWBQKgysLGCwL2r7SGDQLh4ri%2BAwLWws7NDwLWwpLPD%2F1HuCAFYzs2seaziWbYEXjDfigP",
                "hidUrlFileIshurim"=>"https%3A%2F,
"cod"=>"3322"
                    );

$fields_string='';
foreach($postarr as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string,'&');

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST      ,1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; MAAU)");

// I made a cookie file and it seems to work
$cookiefile = "d:/cookie.txt";
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiefile); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiefile);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT , 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  ,1);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER      ,1);  // DO NOT RETURN HTTP HEADERS
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$temp=curl_exec($curl);
$info = curl_getinfo($curl);

$html = mb_convert_encoding($temp, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'utf-8'); 
echo "ERRCODE: ".curl_error($curl);
echo '<br /><br />';
echo "INFO : ";
print_r($info);
echo '<br /><br />';
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
echo "CODE: ".$httpcode;
echo '<br /><br />';
echo "CODE: ".$httpcode;
echo '<br /><br />';
echo "VARS: ".$vars;
echo '<br /><br />';
//echo $html;

curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.*******.******.***");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT , 0);

echo "<br /><br /><b>2nd</b><br /><br />";
$temp=curl_exec($curl);
$info = curl_getinfo($curl);

$html = mb_convert_encoding($temp, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'utf-8'); 
echo "ERRCODE: ".curl_error($curl);
echo '<br /><br />';
echo "INFO : ";
print_r($info);
echo '<br /><br />';
echo $html;
```

Can't get that to even start to work. It starts with returning me a 200 OK, instead of 302, and sometimes I also get a 500.

I know the ASPX vars might actually be crucial, but if my browser can make these vars and send them to the server, can't cURL do the same ?

Thanks for any help !!

Comment: The whole point of a CAPTCHA is to prevent people from doing exactly what you are trying to do. If they want to make this data available programatically, they will provide an API.

Comment: OMG the source of `https://www.misim.gov.il/gmrepishur/base_form.aspx` is a complete mess, you have fancy quotes instead of `"` all over your code and there's a suspicious refresh rate

Comment: #DaveRandom, captcha is used ok. I am not scraping the DB, but rather show the user his own image instead of the site. I then send thatcode to the very site to verify. Captcha is doing its job.

Comment: Please document all URLs according to the pictzures they belong to and a flowchart how to pass through each and of which variables / cookies you know so far.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone: Heh, welcome to Israel government sites.

Comment: 302 is a redirect. You can't save POST data through redirect. So you need to figure why and where that 302 redirect you get leads you. From the log you provided, you a POST request and it gets redirected to another page while POST data is intact. That makes no sense.

Comment: If your problem is solved please add your solution and mark it as the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem solved.
It was a matter of using the correct headers.
Following the reports from the browser, I went through all steps and the result showed up.

I went through each step by using:

```
curl_init
curl_setopt()
..
curl_setopt()
curl_exec()
curl_close()
```

This way I had to manually set each request and go through the settings. It made the code longer, but much easier to understand.

I had thoughts about the site using some javascript special code to make the site work, so I was troubled a lot by all the extra,  javascript code, which turned out unnecessary.

It was all about being alot more organized and following the correct header settings.

Moreover, since this was an `ASPX` site, I had to read and memorize the `VIEWSTATE` and `VALIDATION` of the last page in each iteration. That is the first and very reason for the 500 internal error server message I used to get all the time.

I used Firebug and LiveHttpHeaders to concolude each step.

Answer (score 1):

"Can't get that to even start to work. It starts with returning me a 200 OK, instead of 302, and sometimes I also get a 500."

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  ,1);
```

You have Curl set to follow any 302 redirects. These will be followed internally inside of Curl and won't be seen by PHP.

Also:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER      ,1);  // DO NOT RETURN HTTP HEADERS
```

The comment does exactly the opposite of what the code does....which seems wrong.

Comment: Please say what you were doing wrong, so that people having the same problem as you in future can see how you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

before u made cURL, u need to review the requeste field used. usually HTTP 500 from aspx is not found the field send..

```
foreach($postarr as $key=>$value) { 
  $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; 
  echo" $fields_string <br> ";
}
```

make sure, that field are not dinamic when u r sending request.. 
Hope this helpfull..

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
```

It kind of simulates the curl like it has a browser name and version.