# curl file download returning internal server error

Tags: php, curl, download

I'm trying to download a file via curl and it processes without error but only returns "Internal server error. Please contact system administrator." Through a browser, on the site, when you click on the link it keeps you on the page and starts downloading the file. If you copy the link location and put it into the browser it returns the same text - "Internal server error. Please contact system administrator."

After a few days of research I'm lost

My Function:

```
public function requestFile($url,$filename){
    $cookie_file_path = "cookiejar.txt"; 
    if(!file_exists($cookie_file_path)) {
        $fh = fopen($cookie_file_path, "w");
        fwrite($fh, "");
        fclose($fh);
    }
    $fp_header = '';
    $agent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)";
    if ( ! ($fp_header = tmpfile())) { die('File not created'); }
    set_time_limit(0);
    $fp = fopen ($filename, 'w+');//This is the file where we save the    information
    $ch = curl_init(str_replace(" ","%20",$url));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 500);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER, $fp_header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE,"text/csv");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); // here it sais to curl to just save it
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,TRUE);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);//get curl response
    print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);

    echo "Headers ===>\n";
    rewind($fp_header); echo stream_get_contents($fp_header);
    echo "<=== Headers\n";
    fclose($fp_header);     
}
```

I've left a bit of debugging code and probably a few extra things I have tried:

curl_getinfo:

```
Array
(
[url] => <hidden>/download_price.php?f=Pricelist.csv
[content_type] => text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
[http_code] => 200
[header_size] => 478
[request_size] => 267
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 19
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 0.249
[namelookup_time] => 0
[connect_time] => 0.015
[pretransfer_time] => 0.202
[size_upload] => 0
[size_download] => 59
[speed_download] => 236
[speed_upload] => 0
[download_content_length] => 59
[upload_content_length] => 0
[starttransfer_time] => 0.249
[redirect_time] => 0
[certinfo] => Array
    (
    )

[redirect_url] => 
)
```

And the Headers

```
Headers ===>
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Sat, 16 Mar 2013 11:25:29 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
Set-Cookie: cookie_test=please_accept_for_session; expires=Mon, 15-Apr-2013 11:25:29     GMT; path=/; domain=<hidden>
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: User-Agent,Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 59
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
<=== Headers
```

I'm guessing there is a certain type of request etc that I'm just missing. Any hints, tips, solutions or other debugging advice would b great.

Thanks
John

The trace from the browser:

```
Request URL:https://<hidden>/download_price.php?f=Pricelist.csv
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:sID=80149acc19e0e2383fa7124e026758a7; cookie_test=please_accept_for_session;  gallery-fadeshow1=3 
Host:<hiden>
Referer:https://<hidden>/account.php
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.152 Safari/537.22
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
f:Pricelist.csv
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:public
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Description:File Transfer
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="Pricelist.csv"
Content-Length:1799461
Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary
Content-Type:application/vnd.ms-excel
Date:Sat, 16 Mar 2013 12:15:02 GMT
Expires:0
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Pragma:public
Server:Apache
Set-Cookie:cookie_test=please_accept_for_session; expires=Mon, 15-Apr-2013 12:15:02 GMT; path=/; domain=<hidden>
Vary:User-Agent
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.2.17
```

Comment: You need to identify which server is having the 500 and then go to that server and look into the error log.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not my server I'm trying to read from so I can't check their logs.

Comment: okay then this is like you wrote: You need to find out what in your request causes the error. You can analyze your browsers request by using some networking tools in the browser. Often called developer-tools or webdeveloper-tools. They can be used to show the exact request with all the headers etc.. All you can do is to compare that with your curl request.

Comment: FYI there is no HTML or annything else return purely the txt "Internal server error. Please contact system administrator." and nothing else.

Comment: I've tried to capture the browser comm's using fidler but with no luck.

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: I'll grab exact request from the browser and paste it in here.

Comment: Trace added above (from chrome)

Comment: Try by adding the `Referer:` that is often checked. Basically you just compare the request you send with curl with the one with chrome and you look for the missing header lines. That is how it works. Troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks. Added a referrer, no luck but he fixing the content type did it.curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE,"application/vnd.ms-excel");

Comment: Thanks, a second eye over things helps sooooo much.

Comment: you're welcome. See as well [cURL - works in browser, not in cURL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10195658/367456)